# xslt selecting all child nodes when only specifying an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML which I am transforming with XSLT to build a link. First my template matches on a node with a specific attribute and stores the value of that attribute which works fine. Then I need to find an node with an id attribute that matches the value that I have just stored. However, when I try to select the node and extract the id attribute for comparison it is selecting all the child nodes of the node I am targeting, even though I am specifying that I want only the id attribute. How can I select only the id attribute?

XML

```
<div>         
            <bibl id="label2212" n="M">
                <date n="created">19401231</date>
                <title level="m">test title 1</title>

                <kw type="subject">Ⓑ ...</kw><!-- EXTRA -->
                <kw type="subject">Ⓔ ...</kw><!-- EXTRA -->
                <kw type="subject">Ⓖ Indonesia &lt; Southeast Asia &lt; Asia</kw><!-- EXTRA -->

                <note type="comment">Linked reference: ABIA 13, 1938/658
                    <xref n="label658">label658</xref>
                </note>
            </bibl>
            <bibl id="label658" n="M">
                <date n="created">19401231</date>
                <title level="m">test title 2</title>

                <kw type="subject">Ⓑ ...</kw><!-- EXTRA -->
                <kw type="subject">Ⓔ ...</kw><!-- EXTRA -->
                <kw type="subject">Ⓖ Indonesia &lt; Southeast Asia &lt; Asia</kw><!-- EXTRA -->
            </bibl>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="note[@type = 'comment' ]/xref[@n]"> 
        <xsl:variable name="n-xref"><xsl:value-of select="@n"/></xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="test"><xsl:value-of select="../../../bibl[@id]"/></xsl:variable>
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href" select="$test"></xsl:attribute>
        </a>

         </xsl:for-each>-->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>enter code here
```

When run the variable test contains all child nodes of bibl node
I have even tried select="../../../bibl[@id=$n-xref]" which did not work either

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post the expected result of your example. -- Hint: use a **key** for cross-references.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `bibl[@id]` selects all child `bibl` elements that have an @id attribute. In your sample, all the `bibl` elements have an @id attribute, so you select them all. I guess you are trying to select the one whose @id attribute matches the value of $n-xref. That would be `bibl[@id=$n-xref]`. You say you tried that and it didn't work; try it again and if it still doesn't work, show us exactly what you did.

Looking more closely, I suspect your next problem is the code `<xsl:attribute name="href" select="$test"/>`. The value of `$test` is a `bibl` element, whereas you want its `@id` attribute. As written, your attribute will be set to the string value of the `bibl` element, which is whitespace.

Incidentally, your code `<xsl:variable name="n-xref"><xsl:value-of select="@n"/></xsl:variable>` should be written `<xsl:variable name="n-xref" select="@n"/>` in the interests of clarity and performance.